# Log when python script failed

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, logging, gnu-screen

I am running a rather complex python script through a screen session on my server. Sometimes, after some hours, it crashes and I can’t figure out why. Since the script runs in screen, I don’t get access to the error when the scrips crashes. Is there any way to extract that info through logging or a simple pipe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nohup` and `&` to run your python command in the background. The default output will log any printed outputs (including the error that terminates your script) in a nohup.out file.  You can specify the file output in Bash using `>`

For example

```
nohup python my_python_script.py > my_output_log &
```

Comment: that seems good. Can I run multiple scrips in paralell and different output files with this?

Comment: Yes, this should be possible. However, you will need to be careful not to mess up your `nohup.out` file if you stick to the default as it will just append the output to the file so you could end up with a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem and I did something like this

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename = os.path.join(script_path, 'error.log'), level = logging.ERROR)
try:
    # some dangerous code here
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(str(e))
    # Now you can kill your script, etc
```

This is going to generate a file 'error.log' with the info of the crash